# Retrain a H2ORandomForestEstimator using different data whilst maintaining hyper parameters

Tags: random-forest, h2o

I have saved an optimised `H2ORandomForestEstimator` model using `h2o.save_model()` (python API). I now want to load this model and re-train it with different variants of my data, whilst maintaining the optimised hyperparams (e.g. ntrees, max_depth).

When I do this by calling `train()` on the loaded models however all the hyperparams appear to be reset to their defaults. What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the checkpointing option, details on how this works can be found in the user guide [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/checkpointing-models.html)

I will repost some of the content for your convenience:

*In real-world scenarios, data can change. For example, you may have a model currently in production that was built using 1 million records. At a later date, you may receive several hundred thousand more records. Rather than building a new model from scratch, you can use the checkpoint option to create a new model based on the existing model.*

*The checkpoint option is available for DRF, GBM, and Deep Learning algorithms. This allows you to specify a model key associated with a previously trained model. This will build a new model as a continuation of a previously generated model. If this is not specified, then the algorithm will start training a new model instead of continuing building a previous model.*

*When setting parameters that continue to build on a previous model, specifically ntrees (in GBM/DRF) or epochs (in Deep Learning), specify the total amount of training that you want if you had started from scratch, not the number of additional epochs or trees you want. Note that this means the ntrees or epochs parameter for the checkpointed model must always be greater than the original value. For example:*

*If the first model builds 1 tree, and you want your new model to build 50 trees, then the continuation model (using checkpointing) would specify ntrees=50. This gives you a total of 50 trees including 49 new ones.
If your original model included 20 trees, and you specify ntrees=50 for the continuation model, then the new model will add 30 trees to the model, again giving you a total of 50 trees.*

*If your oringinal model included 20 trees, and you specify ntrees=10 (a lower value), then you will receive an error indicating that the requested ntrees must be higher than 21.*